# why is cpu load too low when polling in 1ns interval

Tags: c, linux, performance, operating-system, system-calls

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec stReq;
    stReq.tv_sec = 0;
    stReq.tv_nsec = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        nanosleep(&stReq,NULL);
        printf("hello,world\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when I run this progress,the `%CPU`column showed by `top` is only about `2%`.

Why is it so low?

Comment: so, remove the `printf` - any effect?

Comment: or, by happenstance you see it printing 1 billion messages per second?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  same result after removing  `printf`

Comment: I have not downvoted, because in my opinion before to downvote **you have to explain why**. In this case it is a very naive question it deserve an explanation. `nanosleep()` can't handle an interval less than the granularity of underlying clock (that is the system tick), as your case with 1nS, effectively scheduling at normal rate. Moreover the `printf()` will not execute in less than 1nS (it interacts with OS and the resulting synchs that will affect again the effective scheduling. As final result the scheduling is standard. The CU charge is the effective code runned compared to full CPU.

Answer (score 0):

1. as this program doing nothing than sleep
2. and your system is has good enough cpu cores.
3. as will which part of cpu it is showing 2 % ? us ,sy,id, wa,st  ?